# 301 Redirection with htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, web, http-status-code-301

I am trying to redirect a file path on my server to another file on another server by using the `.htaccess` file. The reason for this is to create a back door on my site in case one of my admin tries to take over my site.

I want to have it redirected from a file called footer.php on the local server's root folder to another file on another server found [here](http://cats.clanteam.com/footer.php) (cats.clanteam.com/footer.php)

I though I could use a simple redirect like this:

```
Redirect 301 /footer.php http://cats.clanteam.com/footer.php
```

However, this does nothing. I'm sorry. I'm new to redirecting files.

Comment: This looks fine. Let me check it out.

Answer (score 1):

I tried this same code on my server. It works fine. Please check if your path is correct.

```
Redirect 301 /footer.php http://cats.clanteam.com/footer.php
```

If your footer.php is under any sub directory, for example /test/footer.php then your redirect code should go like this

```
Redirect 301 /test/footer.php http://cats.clanteam.com/footer.php
```

Comment: Thank you. Let me try this once again. Maybe I experienced a glitch?

Comment: It still fails. It still shows the local file on the original server.

Comment: ok then just try removing the leading slash from /footer.php. btw, what is your webserver? apache or lighttpd?

Comment: Removing the leading slash does nothing. My server runs Apache. My original server is hosted by three-words and the other server is hosted by Zymic.

Comment: everything fine. It should work. Or else you can do one thing if it is urgent for you. Just put a header("location:url") in your footer.php file.